# What is the name of this book?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Anyone knows the name of this book: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/books/meg/meg_ch12.pdf? I've already tried to find it online and in the maa catalog without success.

I need help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [Methods for Euclidean Geometry](http://www.maa.org/publications/books/methods-for-euclidean-geometry) by Owen Byer, Felix Lazebnik, and Deirdre L. Smeltzer (ISBN: 978-0-88385-763-2).  The webpage I linked to has your link under "Sample Chapter 12."

Answer (score 6):

The search "Chapter 12 Affine Transformations" leads me to the page of the book [Methods for Euclidean Geometry](http://www.maa.org/publications/books/methods-for-euclidean-geometry) on the MAA site. This further agrees with the `meg` prefix in the html of your file.

Answer (score 5):

It *certainly* is [Methods for Euclidean Geometry](https://books.google.com/books?id=W4acIu4qZvoC&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=The+order+of+matrices+in+this+multiplication+matches+the+order+of+the+corresponding+functions+in+the+notation&source=bl&ots=a8oGrm8ccb&sig=fev850JwePHIURM1nEA5iK0mOSo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zYIwVaHRHqGwsAT9w4DwCA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=The%20order%20of%20matrices%20in%20this%20multiplication%20matches%20the%20order%20of%20the%20corresponding%20functions%20in%20the%20notation&f=false) by Owen Byer, Felix Lazebnik, and Deirdre L. Smeltzer. [The link matches footnotes for the 6th footnote with a preview.]